# Is it possible to count the number of repetitions of a string in a single cell of mysql table without using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a large table (mysql) which stores paragraphs in one of its columns. I would like to count the number of times a specific string is repeated in this column. (PS : I am not interested in counting the number of rows in which the string is present)
For example consider the following three rows in that column

```
---------------------------------
this is a very very big paragraph
---------------------------------
this is a very big paragraph
---------------------------------
this is a small paragraph
---------------------------------
```

In this case if I search for ' very ' it must return me '3',
if I use the below command it would return me '2'.

```
select count(*) from table_name where column_name like ' very ';
```

and I am not interested in it.

Is this possible in mysql? or will I need to fetch each paragraph and use php to count the repetation of the string? I am new to SQL.

Comment: Your query works fine because you have only 2 times word "very" in you table. It is 1st and 2nd row. Third row don't contain string "very".

Comment: yes but in the first cell the string very is repeated twice. And I need to count the repetition also. Is this possible?

Comment: @MateiMihai Thank you... This was what I was looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 SELECT 
        SUM(ROUND (   
            (
                LENGTH(column_name)
                - LENGTH( REPLACE ( column_name, "very", "") ) 
            ) / LENGTH("very")        
        )) AS count    
    FROM table_name
```